# Reorder matrix columns by matching column names to vector of names

Tags: r, string, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix with column names and a vector of names in a different order.

Matrix column names:

```
c("colname1", "colname2", "colname3", "colname4", "colname5")
```

Vector of names:

```
c("colname4", "colname3", "colname2", "colname5", "colname1")
```

I am trying to order the matrix columns in the same order as the names in the vector.

I have tried:

```
test <- match(colnames(matrix1), colnames(matrix2))`
```

but it didn't work. Do you know any alternative?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Index the matrix with the `[`-operator and the vector of column names in the desired order:

```
col.order <- c("colname4","colname3","colname2","colname5","colname1")
    M[ , col.order]
```

Comment: If it is a `data.table`, you can use [the .. undocumented feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45381491/1048186): `M[ , ..col.order]`

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr:

```
M %>% select(col.order)
```

If you want arrange the columns order based on another data frame:

```
M %>% select(names(df))
```