# Understand the meaning of[.... with=F][[1]]

Tags: r, data.table

I am doing practicing exercise based on the problems and solutions for data.table in R. The problem was: get the row and column positions of missing values in a data table. The solution code is used " [.....with=F][[1]]. I am not understanding this part of that code and expecting expert opinion to make my concept clear on that.

```
for(i in 1:NROW(DT)){
  for(j in 1:NCOL(DT)){
    curr_value <- DT[i, j,with=F][[1]]
```

I can understand first two lines, but not understanding ,with=F and then [[1]]
What the meaning of with=F and why has been used [[1]] after than that. Why there is double bracket with 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in `data.table`, `with = FALSE` allows you to select columns named in a variable.

Consider the following minimal example,

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(mtcars)
```

Let's select the following columns from `dt`

```
cols <- c(1, 7)
```

The following command will produce an error

```
dt[, cols]
```

Instead you can use `with = F`

```
dt[, cols, with = F]
```

From `?data.table`

> When with=TRUE (default), j is evaluated within the frame of the data.table;
>   i.e., it sees column names as if they are variables.

A shorter alternative is to use

```
dt[, ..cols]
```

See also [Why does “..” work to pass column names in a character vector variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380628/why-does-work-to-pass-column-names-in-a-character-vector-variable)

Comment: Thanks Maurits Evers for your detail explanation on With=F part. It is really helpful. You also elaborated it more with double dot ... Much Appreciated!!